# Install Grub2 (with EFI-IA32 support) to the ESP partition from within Windows 8.1 (32-bit) - Bay Trail tablet

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, grub, uefi, 32-bit

This is a very complicated idea, and it's been stuck in my head for a while now, so bear with me.

In this question, when I say "Grub2", I am referring to the "EFI-IA32 version". The device I will be using contains a 32-bit UEFI BIOS, but has a 64-bit CPU.

I want a folder/archive that I can download, that contains a pre-compiled Grub2 and all of its configuration files (preferably the latest version).

I do NOT want 'Grub4DOS' 'SuperGrub2' or anything like that, I want the same Grub2 that is installed alongside Ubuntu 15.04, 14.10, ect...

I want to be able to COPY this Grub2 folder into my ESP partition, and then use my 32-bit UEFI BIOS to enter Grub2, and boot an OS.

And before you start telling me it's "impossible becase 32 and 64 bit don't work together", I know for a fact it will work, because [I have done it before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619872/installing-ubuntu-14-10-64-bit-on-a-windows-8-bay-trail-atom-tablet/619873#619873) with a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10 on a 32-bit UEFI.

I understand that I could just install ubuntu instead of going through all this, but I'm specifically trying to avoid installing a seperate OS just to get a tiny bootloader onto my ESP.

in case you still don't understand, [GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-IA32 version)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/grub-efi-ia32), here's the link to the Ubuntu package that I want to be used to make the pre-compiled folder (source is listed here as well).

Any answers that have anything to do with "you can't run a 64-bit OS on 32-bit" or "What's the point" will be flagged as off-topic, you have been warned.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only pre-built GRUB `.efi` binary in Ubuntu is the signed version for AMD64; the unsigned 64-bit and 32-bit binaries are built at install time so that they can point to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Your best bet may be to [custom-build the binary you want.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) OTOH, it's conceivable that some other distribution has a pre-built binary that would work for your purposes, but I haven't checked them all. Based on some test installations I have, I'd look into OpenSUSE's packages, which seem to use `grub.cfg` on the ESP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

I downloaded the newest Ubuntu (15.04, 64-bit) ISO file, I extracted the `/boot` and the `/EFI` folders from the root of the ISO. I copied the folders to my ESP partition, and edited the `grub.cfg` file as needed (in `EFI/boot/`), and copied the `bootIA32.efi` file to the `EFI/boot` folder.

I now have a fully working 64-bit Grub2 on a 32-bit UEFI BIOS self-contained in the ESP!

Now, if anyone would care to take a look at [my other question about Grub2](https://superuser.com/questions/924497/grub-rescue-command-line-chainloading-windows-7-installer), that would be fantastical.

Comment: The bootia32.efi file is used in conjunction with Grub binaries and config files (provided by the live ISO) to boot into a fully working 64-bit Ubuntu installation. Changing the configuration in grub.cfg allows me to boot any OS compatible with Grub2, however, EFI chainloading is not supported for Windows.