# Grub rescue command line, chainloading Windows 7 installer

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi, grub2, intel-atom

I currently have grub2 installed on a Baytrail tablet along with Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) and Windows 8.1 (32-bit). The tablet comes with 32-bit UEFI only firmware, and a 64-bit atom processor.

Using Grub2 (IA32) I can boot any number of 64-bit linux os's, but I've yet to find clear instructions on how to chainload a windows 7/8 installer using the Grub command line.

As of now, I have a (legally obtained) Windows 7 "Home Premium" recovery ISO made into a bootable USB drive.

Does anybody have clear and concise instructions on how to boot/chainload a windows 7 installer from a USB drive, using the Grub2 command line?

Answer (score 0):

Just have been there too (where you are right now)
And if you tablet is a Toshiba 10"... we are brothers in arms... ;-)

Just add this entry to your GRUB2 menu

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod ntldr
     insmod ntfs
     ntldr (hd0,msdos1)/bootmgr
}
```